# How to find something in a json file using Bash

Tags: json, jq

I would like to search a JSON file for some key or value, and have it print where it was found.

For example, when using `jq` to print out my Firefox' extensions.json, I get something like this (using "..." here to skip long parts) :

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 31,
  "addons": [
    {
      "id": "wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net",
      "syncGUID": "{e6369308-1efc-40fd-aa5f-38da7b20df9b}",
      "version": "2.0.0",
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Say I would like to search for "wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net", and would like an output which shows me where it was found with something like this:

```
{ "addons": [ {"id": "wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net"} ] }
```

Is there a way to get that with `jq` or with some other json tool?

I also tried to simply list the various `id`s in that file, and hoped that I would get it with `jq '.id'`, but that just returned `null`, because it apparently needs the full path.

In other words, I'm looking for a command-line json parser which I could use in a way similar to Xpath tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your example with modifications to make it valid JSON:

```
< input.json jq -c --arg s wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net '
  paths as $p | select(getpath($p) == $s) | null | setpath($p;$s)'
```

produces:

```
{"addons":[{"id":"wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net"}]}
```

### Note

If there are N paths to the given value, the above will produce N lines.  If you want only the first, you could wrap everything in `first(...)`.

### Listing all the `"id"` values

> I also tried to simply list the various ids in that file

Assuming that `"id"` values of `false` and `null` are of no interest, you can print all the "id" values of interest using the jq filter:

```
.. | .id? // empty
```

Comment: For the id values, when I use `.. | .id?` I get a lot of nulls

Comment: That's why the trailing `// empty` is needed.

Comment: Ah thanks I misread it as a comment, it indeed works

Answer (score 4):

The `path()` function comes in handy:

```
$ jq -c 'path(.. | select(. == "wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net"))' input.json
["addons",0,"id"]
```

The resulting path is interpreted as "In the addons field of the initial object, the first array element's id field matches". You can use it with `getpath()`, `setpath()`, `delpaths()`, etc. to get or manipulate the value it describes.